# Sharing URL on android doesn't show up as link. React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to share a deep-link to my app with a message using **react-native-share**.

The massage is there and so is the URL, but the URL is appearing as a String of array with the link in it.

> Something like :["app://app/home"]

I want it to be a clickable link to my app,
IOS works fine for me.

**My code:**

```
import Share from 'react-native-share';

shareLink()  {
    Share.open({
        title: 'Welcome',
        message: 'this is a link to the home page',
        url: 'app://app/home'
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Thanks!